# Excel How to extract distinct values not in second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I write an (array) formula to extract distinct values that do not occur in a second list?

For example

Source list

```
 - Apple
 - Apple
 - Banana
 - Carrot
 - Carrot
 - Blueberry
```

Exclusion list

```
- Carrot
```

Expected output

```
- Apple
- Banana
- Blueberry
```

Comment: If you have Excel 2019 or higher, maybe you could try something like `=CONCAT(SI($A$1:$A$5<>$C$1;$A$1:$A$5))` but entered as ArrayFormula, and where A1:A5 would be your source list and C1 would be Exclusion list. That would be only a part, still need to remove duplicates. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula described at [C2:C4] to get your distinct value:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$7)+COUNTIF($B$2,$A$2:$A$7),0),0),"")
```

or with excel365 described at [E2:E4]:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A7,A2:A7<>B2))
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. Now to see if my laptop can handle this with +/-20k rows in each list ;)

Comment: Hi, Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Excel 365 or the Excel web app, then try:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(IF(A1:A5<>"Carrot",A1:A5,"")),,-1)
```

[image]

*(this is a spill-down, not a standard array formula)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately my 365 does not seem to have SORT or UNIQUE, so that's a no-go for me.

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `D2`, copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$7)-ROW(A$2)+1/(A$2:A$7<>C$2)/(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A$2:A$7)=0),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. That seems to work only if the Exclusion list has a single value though. It does not accept a range of values (for example C$2:C$3) as a substitute for C$2.